# Difference Between Defaultscope() And Beforefind()?

Tags: php, yii

I have a code for defaultScope:

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    $currentdb  = explode('=', Yii::app()->db->connectionString);

    return array(
         'condition'=> "tenant=:tenant",
         'params' => array(":tenant"=>$currentdb[2]));
}
```

And this code for Beforefind:

```
public function beforeFind() {
    $currentdb  = explode('=', Yii::app()->db->connectionString);
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->condition = "tenant=:tenant";
    $criteria->params = array(":tenant"=>$currentdb[2]);

    $this->dbCriteria->mergeWith($criteria);
    parent::beforeFind();
}
```

I am getting same result in both the functions. Which function is better and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that both can accomplish what you want, but for me the best usage is using scopes. In the yii guide we can find the following definition for scopes:

> A named scope represents a named query criteria that can be combined
>   with other named scopes and applied to an active record query.

It's is what you want to do: apply some query criteria before executing the query. And since you want those criteria to be added on every query then `defaultScope` is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. I'm having a database with records for multiple users and I'm trying to filter on those records that should be visible for the current user only. I got stuck today on trying to fixing that with `defaultScope` and I found out that `beforeFind` is the way to go in this case. The problem can be nailed down to the fact that `beforeFind` doesn't seem to be used on the relations while `defaultScope` is. This means you get stuck when you apply criteria in your `defaultScope` of an object with relations that are eagerly loaded with alike criteria because of the order in which the criteria are applied in the joins.

Let me try to explain this with [Yii's blog guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar): when we only want the posts of the current author, we could write the following `defaultScope`:

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->with('author');
$c->addInCondition('author.author_id', array(1,2,3));
return $c;
```

When using `$post->author`, we will find out that `author.author_id` is applied before author is defined as a join. This is not the best example, but you will find yourself having these problems when having more than two joins in your relations.

Therefore, I would suggest using `beforeFind` instead of `defaultScope`.